# formatting text to add new lines in Javascript / react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My front end application recieves data from a backend service. The data is returned in an array . Sample data is

```
complete_details = [['key1','value1','recommendation1'],['key2','value2','recommendation2']]
```

I then display this data in a REACT component which works fine.
Now I also need to format this data for another application, the other application expects the data to be present in a format such as

```
||Key||Value||Recommendation||
|key1|value1|recommendation1|
|key2|value2|recommendation2|
```

I have a function which is called while clicking a button which is meant to copy this formatted text to clipboard. onCopy function is as follows

```
let formattedReport = '||Key||Value||Recommendation||\n';
let fLine = ''
fLine = fLine + '|' +complete_details.map(item => item.join('|')) + '|\n'
formattedReport = formattedReport + fLine;
```

However when this is written to the variable fLine, there are no new lines added. Can you help me spot what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding new lines wrongly. `complete_details.map` returns an array, so you need to join it by pipe again.

## Working Code

```js
complete_details = [
  ['key1', 'value1', 'recommendation1'],
  ['key2', 'value2', 'recommendation2']
];
let formattedReport = '||Key||Value||Recommendation||\n';
let fLine = ''
fLine = fLine + complete_details.map(item => `|${item.join('|')}|`).join('\n')
formattedReport = formattedReport + fLine;
console.log(formattedReport);
```

Answer (score 1):

can you replace your complete_details mapping with the below one. It may resolve your issue.

```
fLine = fLine + complete_details.map(item => { return '||' + item.join('||') + '||\n'}).join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following example

```js
const complete_details = [
  ["key1", "value1", "recommendation1"],
  ["key2", "value2", "recommendation2"],
];
const header = "||Key||Value||Recommendation||\n";
const output = complete_details
  .map((entry) => "|" + entry.join("|") + "|")
  .join("\n");

  console.log(header + output);
```